# Pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package-managers

I'm having problems with installing a package using `pip`. I tried:

```
pip install jurigged
```

Causing these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jurigged (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jurigged
```

I checked if `pip` was up to date which was the case. I'm on *Python 3.7.4*.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/jurigged/), `jurigged` is only supported as of Python >= 3.8 (see also [here](https://github.com/breuleux/jurigged/blob/master/pyproject.toml))

`pip` doesn't find anything to install because you do not meet the requirements.

Upgrade to Python >= 3.8 and do the same: `pip install jurigged`

Comment: this is my case as well. However, I installed PY 3.8 but the package I'm gonna install available to PY 3.7.... how am I gonna solve it?

Answer (score 9):

1 - You had installed `python3` but your python in `/usr/bin/python` may be still the older version so run the following command to fix it

```sh
python3 -m pip install <pkg>
```

2 - The other possible reason could be initially forgetting the `-r`: Use `pip install -r requirements.txt` the `-r` is essential for the command.

3 - If still not working, there is one more way to fix this error. try this but first, get the version of your package

```sh
python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade PACKAGE==VERSION.VERSION.VERSION
```

4 - You know sometimes the package already exists then also we get this error, so try to check if u are able to import or not.

5 - Try `pipwin` instead of `pip` sometimes if the problem is with pip this works as a magic

6 - Don't forget to turn on your internet, strange but it happens sometimes.

let me know if the problem persists. But as per my guess, it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

for me it helped to run:
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org *libraryName*

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by typing

```
 pip install pandas --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

to cmd
AND
If you want to fix this setting, in window, make file `%HOME%\pip\pip.ini` and add code below to the file,

```
    [global]trusted-host = pypi.org
                           files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).